# How to check whether a variable is an instance of a module's subclass using rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, module, instance, subclass

I have a class structure that looks like this:

```
module MyModule

    class MyOuterClass

        class MyInnerClass

        end

    end

end
```

I'm trying to make sure that a variable was correctly instantiated as a MyInnerClass using Rspec.  printing the type of the class, it was MyModule::MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass.  However, if I try to run the line

```
expect{@instance_of_MyInnerClass}.to be_an_instance_of(MyModule::MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass)
```

I get the error "You must pass an argument rather than a block to use the provided matcher."  Additionally, the classes are in another location, so I can't just check

```
[...] be_an_instance_of(MyInnerClass)
```

Rspec complains that MyInnerClass is an uninitialized constant.  So, I would like to ask how to verify that a variable is an instance of MyInnerClass using RSpec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Don't Pass a Block

Rspec 3.x uses an expect *method* rather than a block syntax (see [RSpec 3 Expectations 3.0](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs)). To get your spec to pass, and clean it up, you can use the following:

```
module MyModule
  class MyOuterClass
    class MyInnerClass
    end
  end
end

describe MyModule::MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass do
  it "is correctly instantiated" do
    expect(subject).to be_an_instance_of MyModule::MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass
  end
end
```

Note the use of the implicit subject, passed as an argument to #expect. You can certainly pass other local or instance variables instead, but in this case *subject* is already defined for you as `MyModule::MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass.new`.

Answer (score 0):

Most of us are using the preferred Rspec syntax, so it would be:

```
expect(@instance_of_MyInnerClass).to be_a MyInnerClass
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  I get NameError: uninitialized constant Base.  Is it an incorrect require convention?  In my spec_helper I require_relative '../lib/my_gem'