# Unable to run rspec unit test "touch_file" in chef cookbook

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

Cookbook: https://github.com/tkidd77/devops-project/tree/master/chef-repo/cookbooks/hello_world

My unit test:

```
it 'touches the correct file' do
  expect { chef_run }.to touch_file ('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm')
end
```

Output when running "chef exec rspec" in git bash:

```
tkidd@tkiddhome MINGW64 /c/git/project/chef-repo/cookbooks/hello_world (master) $ chef exec rspec .F

Failures:

  1) hello_world::default touches the correct file
     Failure/Error: expect { chef_run }.to touch_file ('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm')
       You must pass an argument rather than a block to use the provided matcher ( file "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm"), or the matcher must implement `supports_block_expectations?`.
     # ./spec/unit/recipes/default_spec.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.07199 seconds (files took 8.68 seconds to load) 2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/unit/recipes/default_spec.rb:37 # hello_world::default touches the correct file
```

Here is the chefspec documentation on using the touch_file test: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/acrmp/chefspec/ChefSpec/API/FileMatchers which specifies using parenthesis instead of brackets around "chef-run", but when I do that, I receive an "undefined method" error:

```
tkidd@tkiddhome MINGW64 /c/git/project/chef-repo/cookbooks/hello_world (master) $ chef exec rspec .F

Failures:

  1) hello_world::default touches the correct file
     Failure/Error: expect (chef_run).to touch_file ('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm')

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `to' for #<ChefSpec::SoloRunner:0x0000000007a241d8>
     # ./spec/unit/recipes/default_spec.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.04001 seconds (files took 4.92 seconds to load) 2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/unit/recipes/default_spec.rb:37 # hello_world::default touches the correct file
```

According to this, rspec 3.0 expects a method instead of a block for the file path, but I don't understand what that would look like. [How to check whether a variable is an instance of a module's subclass using rspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144460/how-to-check-whether-a-variable-is-an-instance-of-a-modules-subclass-using-rspe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be `expect(chef_run).to touch_file('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm')`. You only use `expect { ... }` with `raise_error` and things like it, most matches use `expect(...)` as a normal call. Also you had an extra space after `touch_file`. `method (args)` is not allowed in Ruby (or at least it is allowed and doesn't do what you think it does).

Comment: That syntax results in:

Failures:

  1) hello_world::default touches the correct file
     Failure/Error: expect(chef_run).to touch_file('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm')

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `resource_collection' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/unit/recipes/default_spec.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: Then the rest of your spec code is not correct setting up the `chef_run` object.

Comment: That is logical, but doesn’t seem to be the case here since the other unit test works using the same chef_run object: describe 'hello_world::default' do
  let :chef_run do
    ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new(platform: 'windows', version: '2016')
  end

    it 'converges successfully' do
      expect { chef_run }.to_not raise_error
    end

Comment: You’re missing a .converge(something) in there

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
describe 'hello_world::default' do

  let :chef_run do
    ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new(platform: 'windows', version: '2016').converge(described_recipe)
  end

     it 'touches the correct file' do
       expect(chef_run).to touch_file('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm')
     end
end
```